# How to call plot.xts when using RScript

Tags: r, xts

UPDATE: Thanks to Joshua's comment I realized the problem wasn't being inside a function, but inside a script. So I've edited the question and also provided my own answer.

---

When I use `plot.xts()` interactively it pops up a graphics window. I just tried it from inside a function (I'm troubleshooting a unit test and wanted some visual help) but nothing appeared. Aha, says I, I know the trick, just use `print`.

But `print(plot.xts(x))` still shows no chart and instead prints my xts object! I.e. it does exactly the same as `print(x)`.

The script I use to run unit tests is:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript --slave

library('RUnit')

options(warn=2) #Turn warnings into errors

#By naming the files runit.*.R, and naming the functions test*(), we can use
#    all the defaults to defineTestSuite().
#NOTE: they have a weird default random number generator, so changed here
#    to match the R defaults instead.
test.suite=defineTestSuite('tests',dirs=file.path('tests'),
    rngKind = "Mersenne-Twister", rngNormalKind = "Inversion")

test.result <- runTestSuite(test.suite)

printTextProtocol(test.result)
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? This works for me: `f <- function(x) plot(x); f(.xts(1:10,1:10))`.

Comment: Thanks Joshua; Your example works for me. I'll investigate this tomorrow, then will probably rephrase or delete this question: I bet it is related to how I run the unit tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script below does two things:

- plot to a device file, as you would in headless setting such as a webserver,
- plot a screen device, I use `x11()` but you could use `win()`.

There is no limitation imposed by `Rscript`. And this has nothing to do with `xts` as you could just as easily plot an `xts` object.

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

set.seed(42)
x <- cumsum(rnorm(100))

png("/tmp/darren.png")
plot(x)
dev.off()

x11()
plot(x)
Sys.sleep(3)  # could wait for key pressed or ...
```

Comment: Thanks Dirk, `x11()` added to my toolbox! Two followup questions, if I may: how do I wait for a keypress (`readline` got ignored), and how do I then remove the chart (I tried `dev.off()`, but that wasn't it)? I tried `x11();plot(x$High);cat("Press enter");readline()`.

Comment: `readLines()` works, waiting for `CTRL-d`. You can also use tck/tk which is event-based, or maybe try `par(ask=TRUE)`.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You cannot use graphics (or input functions like `readline`) when using RScript.</strike> However an RScript is still just R, so when you want to add something interactive (e.g. for troubleshooting) start R, then type:

```
source('run_tests.R')
```

When run this way, a line like this shows the chart:

```
plot(x$High);cat("Press a key");readline()
```

When run directly from the commandline with `./run_tests.R` that line gets quietly ignored.

Comment: Gosh, no -- *of course* you can plot inside an RScript. See my answer.